# How to get regex inner html in ubot studio

Tags: regex

Hi i have an text inside ubot studio that i am trying to scrape from
The function that i use is find regular expresion and the list item is this:

```
 <td class="amt base"> 

      $136 

 </td>
```

How can i get the $136 with regex?
I tried to use the following:

```
<td class="amt base">(.*)</td>
<td class="amt base">(*)</td>
<td class="amt base">*</td>
```

But none of them seem to work.
Thanks alot for sharing your regex knowladge.

Comment: Depending on which languages you have available you might have much better options than using regex for parsing HTML.

Comment: This is the only thing that i can do with Ubot Studio. Its not a language its a visual bot constructor and does not give you much room to move..

Answer (score 0):

How about the `/s`

```
/(?:<td class="amt base">)(.*)(?:<\/td>)/s
```

**[Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eC9fN6)**

- **`/s`** will treat the string as single line. With this change change **`.*`** will match any character whatsoever, even a newline, which normally it would not match.
- **`?:`** the none matching group is optional here but it was added to make a single group match.
- **`\/`** it is also important to scape **`\`** as they have an special meaning in Regex.

> **Important:** I did not see a language specified in your post and `/s` may not be supported by some languages like Javascript or Ruby.

**Update**

Even though it is uncertain if it will work with all your input value you could try this:

**[Online Demo 2](http://regex101.com/r/yS8hO7)**

```
/(?:<td class="amt base">\s+)(.*)(?:\s+<\/td>)/
```

Comment: Yes but how about if this is not suporting /s ? Got any ideas what i can do first to remove the /newline ? with a formal regex?

Answer (score 0):

\d* will match any list of digits.

\$\d* will match a dollar sign and then a string of digits.

The options that you tried do not work because .* stops at the end of each line. You are attempting to match a multi-line statement.

Answer (score 0):

use this regular expression which will scrape a dollar sign and the digits ater:

```
\$\d+
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer. Simply stating a possible solution is not enough. You have to explain WHY that solution is correct. The purpose is to educate future readers. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer